# story about a perfect average citizen

Tags: story-identification, dystopia

Year ago I read a dystopian story about a guy who was found to be an **exact average** of several parameters.
A doctor scribbled a note "average" (or similar) on this character's health records, and someone else noticed this comment and did the actual math, proving he was exactly average.
This lead to the whole society striving for average, and everything went downhill from there.

Any idea about the story title and/or its author? Thanks.

This is not "Franchise" by Isaac Asimov, by the way.

Comment: Thanks @user14111 As written above, it's not "Franchise". The story I am after has nothing to do with elections

Comment: https://poets.org/poem/unknown-citizen

Comment: Thanks @Valorum This is not the story I am looking for, but it's a nice poem.

Comment: and of course you are right! Apologies but I didn't notice the accepted answer was different from the top one. 

So yes, the story I was after is "Null-P" by William Tenn. Thanks @user14111

Comment: On my defense, that answer is *not* to the original question. :-)

Comment: @DeepShadow Damn it, you're right! That is too confusing. Instead of closing this question as a duplicate, I guess it should be reopened and answered here.

Comment: @user14111 - In this instant OP had conflated the two stories but Null-P is still the accepted answer to the other one

Comment: @Valorum If the next user looking for "Null-P" finds this question, and is pointed to that old question, he is liable to get confused the way DeepShadow and I were, especially since Stack Exchange doesn't move the accepted answer to the top. I think somebody should put a clear answer here, and make this the dupe target.

Comment: @Valorum If both questions had answers, there's no doubt this one should be the dupe target, because this question gives a much better description of "Null-P" than the old one. Both the question and the top answer are going to scare away people who are looking for "Null-P".

Comment: @user14111 - Worth editing the dupe answer to make it clearer that he was conflating several stories.

Comment: @Valorum If you think that's worth doing, go ahead. Editing the dupe answer won't help the dupe question being a piss poor description of "Null-P".

Comment: Valorum, user14111: thanks both for the comments. I'm sure the answers are fine - maybe a little bit confusing but they can all be found :-)

Comment: @DeepShadow I responded to your flag, but I'd suggest raising a meta post about this.